# How to embed CA-certificates with spring-boot:build-image?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, buildpack

I need to add self-signed certificates to a spring-boot docker image using `spring-boot:build-image` and `paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates` but couldn't get it working.

So:

- where to put the certificates to add?
- in which format?
- how to define `paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates` bindings?
- should any additional argument be provided to `mvn spring-boot:build-image`?

What I tried with no success so far:
update pom.xml `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <image>
                <bindings>
                    <binding>${basedir}/bindings/ca-certificates:/platform/bindings/ca-certificates</binding>
                </bindings>
            </image>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-image</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

from `${basedir}` folder:

```sh
mkdir bindings
mkdir bindings/ca-certificates
echo "ca-certificates" > bindings/ca-certificates/type
cp ~/.ssh/mycert.pem bindings/ca-certificates/
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

Edit: moved image bindings configuration directly under boot-plugin (rather than inside a specific execution) as suggested by @nick-valanos and solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it. Maven configuration above is for maven `package` target, not `spring-boot:build-image`.

Here is the complete procedure:

- create `bindings/ca-certificates` folder at maven project root and add to it:

  - `type` file containing just `ca-certificates`
  - CA certificatates you want to be embedded (in PEM format)
- in pom.xml, add a `build-image` execution to `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with `${basedir}/bindings/ca-certificates:/platform/bindings/ca-certificates` image binding as configured in my question
- run `mvn clean package`

Comment: Following Paketo docs i provided such ca cert at runtime mounting local volume as Service Binding Specification for Kubernetes. It worked at first attempt.

Comment: from where can we generate pem certificate file?

Comment: https://github.com/ch4mpy/self-signed-certificate-generation

Answer (score 5):

I kind of had the same issue and I found your post really helpful. After a bit playing around, I found that your configuration would also work with `spring-boot:build-image` with the following alterations:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <bindings>
                <binding>${basedir}/bindings/ca-certificates:/platform/bindings/ca-certificates</binding>
            </bindings>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, I added the `<configuration>` immediately after `<plugin>`. That way, it seems that it is parceable by `spring-boot:build-image`

Comment: I just realized that I found your answer usefull enough to edit my configuration with it but had not upvoted it. Sry about that and thanks for your contribution.